# Has anyone got a reasonable script for purging old release versions from nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

Some say this is taboo however [acknowledge there are good reasons](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20871791-Can-I-delete-releases-from-Nexus-after-they-have-been-published-) for removing release versions.

So initially I thought I could just write a `find` statement to find directories for a given `groupId` and delete the directories, i.e.

```bash
find /data/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/releases/com/example \
    -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +14
```

Then use this to delete the matched paths, there are however two problems with this.

1. I don't want to delete everything if there hasn't been a release in 14 days, I actually want to keep three copies.
2. The groupId may be shared, unlikely, though two packages could be set `com.example:app1` and `com.example.tools:lib1`. This would likely be an error in the pom creator though I would like to cater for it.

I figured I could probably get around this by looking at the `maven-metadata.xml` but didn't want to have to start something if someone else already has a solution.

Note of course that once complete an index rebuild would need to occur on the affected repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out newer versions of nexus now provide this capability out of the box.

Scheduled task `Remove Releases From Repository` now provides exactly what I'm after in version `2.6.4-02`.

I had previously been running 2.3.

Comment: I was just going to mention that to you. I am glad you found it. Let us know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: Thanks Manfred, wish I were smart enough to upgrade first before spending time writing an initial script though, this task actually works exactly as expected.

Comment: In general I would suggest to always have a look at the new releases. E.g. 2.7 has some very nice UI enhancements coming up. Also check out the Nexus Live recordings (http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGB2s-U5FSWPHJd4EEEFgmcLJUc-_1Pcs)

Comment: Thanks Manfred, I did intend to but SO makes you wait 24 hours on answering your own question and it slipped my mind to come back to it.